# Can I travel to US using B1/B2 while DS-160 has been submitted for L-1 visa stamping?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I am currently applying L1 visa and almost done with DS160 form filling. Am going to submit the form and make the appointment for L1 visa interview.

Now my US manager wants to bring me back to US for a short training using my B1/B2 before the L1 visa interview. My main concern here is my I-94 will get updated for sure if I make the business travel, and hence some information like 'last entry to US' in submitted DS-160 won't be latest. Will this cause any issue?

Answer (score 6):

I went through the L1 process some years ago and was told by the lawyer handling the paperwork that under no circumstances to travel to, through or via the US until it was completed and I had the visa in my passport.

Maybe your employer is using a specialist firm to handle your petition and they can advise, or perhaps call the embassy and see if it'll cause a delay?

Comment: So very this.  Talk to the lawyers. Depending on the exact situation you *may* be able to travel, but they will want to know about it beforehand!